# Restoring saved Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins

I have been trying to restore saved Jenkins job but cant seem to accomplish it. all i have done is to copy the builds in to the job folder and copy the config.xml file, and click reload configuration from disk. but the builds fail to appear on the dashboard. 
any help much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: This isn't a programming question... surely there is a Jenkins related support forum or reddit or somewhere more appropriate where this question can be asked?

Comment: Hi Daniel, there is no error displayed. when i click reload configuration from the disk no error is displayed. however, i can't seem to get the jobs restored on the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

i managed to restore the old jobs.  all i have done is to copy all the jobs to .jenkins\job folder. then just click reload configuration from the disk. that is all there is to it. however i have noticed that the credentials.xml has to be present in the jenkins directory for the transfer to work
.